# Cannot scale spark job execution time

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, vmware, minio

I built an ETL pipeline to process terabytes of data. To achieve that goal, I set up a Spark Cluster (Scala) and [MinIO](https://min.io/) server for object data storage.
I can process and save 200 gigabytes in roughly 30 minutes using 10 virtual machines, for Spark Processing.
The issue I have is that I am not able to scale. Meaning, if I double the number of spark virtual machines, this does not affect processing time.

I need some guidance to identify the bottleneck.

**ARCHITECTURE SUMMARY.**

- I use virtual machines set up on-premises using **VMWare ESXi 6** Physical machines (which host VMs) are on a **1 GB** network.
- There is **no over commitment for vCPU nor RAM**
- Spark VMs: 16VCPU, 64 GB RAM
- MinIO (Storage). 16vCPU, 64GB RAM, Configured using RAID0

**SOME DETAILS ABOUT DATA PROCESSING**
The process is straight.

- Read data from 2 sources on MinIO,
- Make a Union of data of two sources,
- Filter out empty values on a column from resulting dataset,
- Apply 2 groupby on that column (I save intermediate values after the first groupby)
- Union the dataset obtained after the groupby operation with the empty columns values
- Save the whole again on MinIO

**MY SPARK CONFIGURATION**
Spark is deployed in Client mode.

```
  mode = "client"
  network.timeout = 1800001 
  rpc.askTimeout = 1800000
  default.parallelism = 320 
  sql.shuffle.partitions = 320 #
  spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled=true
  spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true
  sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile = "100000" // spark.write
  sql.files.maxPartitionBytes = "31457280" // spark.read
  sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes = "30m"

  sql.objectHashAggregate.sortBased.fallbackThreshold = -1
  memory.fraction = 0.85

  # executor configs
  executor.cores = 4 
  executor.memory = 12g 
  executor.memoryOverhead = 3g
  total.executor.cores = 160
  executor.instances = 40
  executor.heartbeatInterval = 1800000
```

Comment: Can you share your data processing code? Helps reviewers to understand what is really happening :) There are many things that can go wrong here, but some things to consider: What is your file format? How many partitions does your output file have? How have you changed your spark job configuration between your runs?

Comment: did you try on HDFS? instead of MINI IO. How do you know Mini IO is not the bottle neck? is external shuffle enabled? Did you check the explain plan of the sql query you are running? If the sql exection is happening on a small st of nodes? Can you remove the group bys and see if the times are scalig? if yes then its sql issue

Comment: @chendu thanks for your input. 
I did not try to scale in prod environment on HDFS. I choose MinIO over HDFS because during development phase, MinIO performed better than HDFS.

I checked explain plan, but I noticed nothing particular that can lead to that issue.

I will switch to HDFS again and re-run same tests.  Furthermore, I will also try to scale with a simple read and copy job without any `group by` to see if I have the same issue.

I will update with my results.

Comment: HDFS is time-tested system. Its likely that it under-performs on less load or when compaction is happening. When processing huge data multiple Executors access multiple HDFS blocks at the same time across the machines which will help in parallelism. I am not sure how it works on MiniIO

Comment: @chendu I did some tests during weekend. I removed group by operations and did only a read and rewrite data jobs. And the issue is still the same. There is no gain in processing time. 

**When processing huge data multiple Executors access multiple HDFS blocks at the same time across the machines which will help in parallelism.**

This is a good point. I will re-configure Hadoop on all nodes today and re-run tests. I will update with results.

Comment: If you can have access to S3, then better get rid of HDFS and use S3. So far with me S3 was also horizontally scalable. This will help you in determining if Disk/ File system is the bottle neck.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the infrastructure you mentioned, in order to scale the spark jobs you also need to scale the data backend. This is similar to how if you have an app which writes to a traditional database, if the amount of requests increase, if you increase the front end workers it won't actually increase the performance until the database is also scale to match the additional requests. You have to consider all bottlenecks in your infrastructure.

So in this case, if you are increasing your spark VM count you also need to scale the MinIO backend accordingly to get the performance increase.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just scale spark to scale your performance, you need to first measure if your MinIO is deployed to your required scale.

From what I can gather you have only deployed MinIO on a single node, there is not only so much storage that can do to serve as you scale your clients.

Just scaling clients is not sufficient.